# VBA : loop through discontinued series of file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a VBA program to gather data from excel files, all name : AAA- i with i going from 1 to 200, but skipping some number.

My code works well but stops and asks me to open the missing file manually. I would like to skip these missing number. How can I proceed ?

Also, sometime I have the date of the day like so : AAA- i ddmmyyyy, I don't know how to ignore this part.

```
 `Sub proto()
   Dim file As String
    Dim i As Integer, nfile As Integer
  
    
    Const DOSSIER = "C:\temp\FOLDER\"
    Const chemin1 = "PROJECT-  "
      
    For i = 1 To 250
    file = DOSSIER & "[" & chemin1 & i & ".xlsm" & "]"
  
    Range("B" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "='" & file & "Sheet1'!K30"
     Range("C" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "='" & file & "Sheet2'!K92"
    
    Next i
end sub
`
```

Thanks,

Program created & to be improved

Comment: You could gather the filenames in to a collection, process the collection to keep only the required filenames and then for each through the collection to do the actual operations on the final set of file names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub proto()
    Dim filepattern As String, filefound As String, formulastring As String
    Dim i As Long, o As Long
    
    Const DOSSIER = "C:\temp\FOLDER\"
    Const chemin1 = "PROJECT-  "

    o = 1
    For i = 1 To 250
        filepattern = DOSSIER & chemin1 & i & " *.xlsm"
        filefound = Dir(filepattern)
        If filefound <> "" Then
            formulastring = DOSSIER & "[" & filefound & "]"
            Range("B" & o).Formula = "='" & formulastring & "Sheet1'!K30"
            Range("C" & o).Formula = "='" & formulastring & "Sheet2'!K92"
            o = o + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

It's effectively the same code, but it tests that the file exists before creating the link and also uses `o` to track what row the data is being written to. (You can write to row `i` instead if you want blank lines when the file doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks! It works fine this way. I just added a string "filename" as "file" is more the directory.

Comment: Hi Matthieu, I've altered my answer with more explanatory variable names and also it will now see any files that match the pattern `C:\temp\FOLDER\PROJECT-  # *.xlsm` where the `#` is a number from 1-250 and `*` is any string of text such as a date.

Comment: Okay it worls well this way ! How can I proceed if I ever have a small typo variation between chemin and i ? Like somtimes there is a space, sometimes not..

Comment: EDIT : I've succeeded by just adding "*" between the 2. Thanks a lot for your help! 
Can I follow the same principle if these file are each located in a folder with their name as folder name ?

Comment: If you're asking if the wildcard `*` can be used within foldernames as well as filenames to search for a matching file in a set of folders, I'm afraid the answer is no. You'd need to ask a different question if you need to be able to do that, and the answer will likely be very different to the above, instead using a recursive search approach.

Comment: @MatthieuAoun If this answer helped you toward your end goal, please mark it as correct and give the contributor credit.

Answer (score 0):

So adding before the loop

> If Dir(fileName) <> "" Then

seems to work as suggested above.

I would like to upgrade the program so it can find the file with a date after the file name, like so
AAA - i - ddmmyyyy.

In my opinion I should ignore the date part that is irrelevant to me but i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: This seems to be an additional and/or separate question. Please amend your original question or submit a new question enitirely.